# Find out when Android project was created (Using Flutter/Dart)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-gradle-plugin

I have small question and could use your professional help please..

I got a project from some company that sell android apps projects.
The problem is like this.. the seller told me that it's a custom made project that he developed in the last 2 months and I opend the project in android studio and I got a feeling that pretty old recycled project.
I saw that Gradle depencises are pretty old version (4.1.0) when today the latest version is 8.0.*
My question is: how can prove that the project is a old project, created date timestamp or something like this?

Thank you :)

Grade depencises are old versions..

Answer (score 0):

You can check for creation date of a **file in its properties** or even search for the **same code on github** to see if there are any matches.

And if you think that it is really old then you should check it for **null safety** and **android x** migration
For `Android X` Migration you need to check your `gradle.properties` file :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Check if these two lines are written or not.

For `null safety`, you just need to run your project and it will be visible in your console screen.

One more thing to check for an old project is to check for its dependency versions if all the dependencies date to an older date then you'll know that it is an old project

Comment: Hi, thanks for you fast response.. please my comment below :)